# Aggregating the attributes from nearby grids and assigning it to the parent grid in a fishnet

Tags: postgis, postgresql, ppygis

I have 700,000 grids generated to cover an administrative area. I want to calculate the sum of an attribute in its neighboring grids till 2nd order and assign it to each grid. To do so I have generated a buffer on each grid and identified which subsequent grids fall under a parent grid and summed their attributes,  but it is taking too long.

Is there a quicker way around this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be solved by a simple update like this:

```
update your_grid 
  set (sum_field1, sum_field2) = 
    (select sum(a.field1), sum(a.field2) 
       from your_grid a 
       where st_touches(a.geometry, geometry))
```

This will update your grid fields with values that are calculated as a sum of fields from neighboring grids (grids touches that one which is updated). For best performance, there should be a spatial index on grid geometry field.

OR if your grid is regular and can be accessed by a row and column indices, then you can use something like this:

```
update your_grid 
  set (sum_field1, sum_field2) = 
    (select sum(a.field1), sum(a.field2) 
       from your_grid a 
       where a.row >= row -1 and a.row <= row + 1 
         and a.col >= col -1 and a.col <= col + 1
         and a.row <> row and a.col <> col)
```

Again, for best performance, there should be index on a row and col fields.

Comment: The solution provided solved the issue for the 1st order (3x3 neighbourhood around the first grid). For the 2nd order (5x5 neighbourhood) i used the st_crosses function and that greatly decreased the query run time. Your solution helped design the solution to the 2nd order problem. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @SiddharthSoni how would you solve the 2nd order window summary using `ST_Crosses`? I suspect the *'greatly decreased [...] query run time'* is due to it not working as expected...

Comment: I generated a buffer and used the st_exteriorring function and st_crosses function to identify the grids that intersect the 2nd order buffer. The cumulative sum of the grid itself, 1st order neighbours and 2nd order neighbours gave the value I wanted.

Comment: @SiddharthSoni if that works for your grid, better use `ST_DWithin` with the same radius as you used for the buffer! Same result, orders of magnitude more efficient (using the index).

Comment: @SiddharthSoni better yet, if your grid is regular, use `a.geom && ST_Expand(b.geom, <sidelength_of_gridcells>)`